# remove ubuntu from duel boot

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot

I have two instances of ubuntu installed in my machine. They are installed in separate partition respectively, so it is a dual boot.  I want to remove one of the instance of the Ubuntu.

Can I just format the partition? Or what is the safe way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

just format one instance of ubuntu and update your grub config